# Oracle conditional WHERE in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to write a stored procedure to select carriers, with an additional parameter 'i_showEmptyCarrier' to specify if empty carriers needs to be hidden or showed.

```
+---------------------------+
|          Carriers         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | label    | location  |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | carrier1 | warehouse |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | carrier2 | warehouse |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | carrier3 | factory   |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I need to query the 'products' table to check if the carrier is empty or not.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                  products                 |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| id | carrierid | productiondate | deleted |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| 1  | 1         | 09/09/2020     | 1       |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| 2  | 1         | 09/09/2020     | 0       |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| 3  | 1         | 09/09/2020     | 0       |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| 4  | 2         | 10/09/2020     | 0       |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| 5  | 2         | 10/09/2020     | 0       |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
```

So in this case carrier3 is empty. 
The stored procedure logic I want to have is:

```
PROCEDURE GetCarriers
(
    i_showEmptyCarrier IN number,
    c_Carriers OUT t_cursor
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN c_Carriers FOR 
SELECT 
label,
(   select count(*) 
    from products 
    where products.carrierid = carriers.carrierid
    and records.deleted = 0
) as nrOfProducts
FROM carriers
if(i_showEmptyCarrier == 1) {
//select carriers without a product
WHERE nrOfProducts = 0 ;
}
else{
//select carriers with a product
WHERE nrOfProducts > 0 ;
}
END GetCarriers;
```

so if 'i_showEmptyCarrier' = 1, then empty carrier no.3 will be selected,

```
+----------+--------------+
| label    | nrOfProducts |
+----------+--------------+
| carrier3 | 0            |
+----------+--------------+
```

otherwise only carrier no.1 and 2 are selected.

```
+----------+--------------+
| label    | nrOfProducts |
+----------+--------------+
| carrier1 | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
| carrier2 | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hello, kindly provide the table structure and sample data. Then tell us how you want the rows to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about modifying the query to use `left join` and `conditional aggregation` and finally comparing the input,

```
SELECT label,nrOfProducts
FROM
(
  SELECT c.label,SUM(CASE WHEN p.deleted = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) nrOfProducts
   FROM carriers c
  LEFT JOIN products p 
  ON p.carrierid = c.id
  GROUP BY c.label
)
WHERE ((&i_showEmptyCarrier = 1 AND nrOfProducts = 0) 
       OR (&i_showEmptyCarrier = 0 AND nrOfProducts > 0));
```

*You can still use the where clause for your query instead of if-else.*

Comment: @cfoppa, May I know the reason behind your un-accept of the answer just to understand better ? It is very important for me to understand here.

Comment: @cfoppa The accepted solution doesn't consider `deleted_flag` and i have no clue how it solves your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You want an inner join in one case and an outer join in the other. As an outer join just means that all columns of the outer-joined row are null, however, you can simply outer join in both cases and only then decide whether to dismiss or keep the outer-joined rows.

In SQL this is simply:

```
select *
from carriers c
left join products p on p.carrierid = c.id
where (:show_empty = 'only non-empty' and p.id is not null)
   or (:show_empty = 'only empty' and p.id is null)
   or (:show_empty = 'all')
```

(And of course you can aggregate this to `count(p.id)`. In that case you can either `group by c.id` or look at one carrier `where c.id = :carrier_id`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure to show only the carrier which is empty or not in this way using an if statement and a cursor which you already tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_get_carriers(
    pi_carrier_flag IN VARCHAR2,
    po_carriers OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    IF pi_carrier_flag = 'Y' THEN
        OPEN po_carriers FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.label, c.location
        FROM carriers c
        LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.carrierid
        WHERE p.deleted = 0 OR p.deleted IS NOT NULL;
     ELSE
        OPEN po_carriers FOR
        SELECT c.id, c.label, c.location
        FROM carriers c
        LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.carrierid
        WHERE p.deleted IS NULL;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
END p_get_carriers;
/
```

in this way you call the stored procedure

```
set serveroutput on
    DECLARE
        v_carrier_flag VARCHAR2(1) := 'N'; -- You can set 'Y' or 'N' as needed
        v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
        carrier_id NUMBER;
        carrier_label VARCHAR2(15);
        carrier_location VARCHAR2(15);
    BEGIN
   
 p_get_carriers(v_carrier_flag, v_cursor);

    LOOP
        FETCH v_cursor INTO carrier_id, carrier_label, carrier_location;
        EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Carrier ID: ' || carrier_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Carrier Label: ' || carrier_label);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Carrier Location: ' || carrier_location);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE v_cursor;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occurred: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a lot of Java (or other programming language) influence. I am not sure what exactly you want. But here is how you can achieve what you want.

```
create or replace procedure p_get_carriers(pi_carrier_flag in varchar2, po_carriers out t_cursor)
is
    lt_cursor   t_cursor;
begin
    select  *
    bulk collect into lt_cursor
    from    records
    where   deleted = case when pi_carrier_flag = 'Y' then 0 else deleted end;
    po_carriers := lt_cursor;
exception
when others then
    po_carriers := null;
end p_get_carriers;
```

Meaning you don't need to have if-else block to handle that. You can do it in the where clause of the query itself.

Note: I am not aware of your table structure and the collection details. I am guessing it and posting the code. You might need to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Hi, i added the table i'm using, thank you for answering my question!